# automapper class and nested class map to one class

Tags: automapper

i have written alot of description but i figured making a picture will make my problem clearer than words

[image: The mapping process]

i have written this to map but it throws an exception

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GenericStory, GenericStoryDisplayViewModel>().ForMember(
            gs => gs.StoryBody,dest => dest.MapFrom( gs => gs));
```

> Trying to map StoryWriting.Web.Models.GenericStory to StoryWriting.Web.ViewModels.StoryBodyViewModel.
>   Using mapping configuration for StoryWriting.Web.Models.GenericStory to StoryWriting.Web.ViewModels.GenericStoryDisplayViewModel
>   Destination property: StoryBody
>   Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>   Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought with AutoMapper you had to map sub-types as well, regardless of if they were contained in another mapped type?

So in this case you'd add

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GenericStory, StoryBodyViewlModel>();
```

and then your current mapping.

EDIT:

I've updated my test case to even match your images and it's functioning as expected:

```cs
public class GenericStory
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavoritedByCurrentUser { get; set; }
    public int StoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public string StoryTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int TotalFavoritedByUsers { get; set; }
}

public class GenericStoryDisplayViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StoryTypeId { get; set; }
    public string StoryTypeName { get; set; }

    public StoryBodyViewModel StoryBody { get; set; }
}

public class StoryBodyViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }

    public int TotalFavoritedByUsers { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavoritedByCurrentUser { get; set; }
}
```

and then my test

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var story = new GenericStory
    {
        Description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....etc",
        Html = "<h1>ZOMG!</hl>\r\n\r\n<h2>BEES!</h2>",
        Id = 9,
        IsFavoritedByCurrentUser = true,
        StoryTypeId = 1,
        StoryTypeName = "ShortStory",
        Title = "Test Story",
        TotalFavoritedByUsers = 1
    };

    var vm = new GenericStoryDisplayViewModel();

    Mapper.CreateMap<GenericStory, StoryBodyViewModel>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<GenericStory, GenericStoryDisplayViewModel>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.StoryBody, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

    Mapper.Map(story, vm);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: it won't map with the default option this is a picture of my try at first it map perfectly then after putting some properties in a class it won't match http://i.stack.imgur.com/WThRO.png

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you try what I suggested? That image doesn't imply anything different from what I implemented.

Comment: works the problem i didn't know i should write     `Mapper.CreateMap<GenericStory, StoryBodyViewModel>();` Million Thanks , if u have written this suggestion earlier then i am very sorry i thought u wrote `Mapper.CreateMap<GenericStory, StoryBodyViewModel>();` again sry if i didn't see it and again million thanks

Comment: Nice sample! Ping from 2017 :)

Comment: This works but can you please explain what below code means? `opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse mapping for configure unflattening. Look at the official [doc](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html#reverse-mapping-and-unflattening)