# Automapper - map nested property

Tags: automapper

I have question about Automapper. This is my usecase:
I have these classes:

Bussiness:

```
public class Item
{
    public NestedItem NestedItem{get;set;}
}

public class NestedItem
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string NestedItemName{get;set;}
}
```

When I want to map *Item* to *ItemViewModel*. Automapper map property `NestedItem.Name` to `NestedItemName`  correctly.
But in the opposite way it doesn´t work. Mapping doesn´t change value of NestedItem.Name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automapper map into nested class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924185/automapper-map-into-nested-class)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a slightly contradictory answer to the link stated above, maybe I just go about my things the awkward way but I believe you can do it within one map. For example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ItemViewModel, Item>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NestedItem, opt => 
         opt.MapFrom(src => new NestedItem(src.NestedItemName));
```

Now of course this would require you to create a new constructor or add a blank constructor and use curly brackets.

I can't comment on performance as AutoMapper is a seriously complicated monster. However this should do the trick.