# AutoMapper ProjectTo() configuration question

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

Not able to map one of the Dto's:

ViewModel:

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
    public TicketDto Ticket { get; set; }

    public CompanyDto Company { get; set; }

    public TicketStateDto TicketState { get; set; }

    public string TicketPriorityName { get; set; }
}
```

Company and TicketState are navigation properties.

Query:

```
var query = _ticketRepository.GetAll() // return IQueryable<Ticket>
             .Include(c=> c.Company)
             .Include(tt => tt.TicketState)
             .Include(ts => ts.TicketPriority)
             .OrderBy(n => n.Id)
        .ProjectTo<TicketViewModel>();
```

Mappings:

```
configuration.CreateMap<Ticket, TicketDto>();
configuration.CreateMap<TicketState, TicketStateDto >();
configuration.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto >();

configuration.CreateMap<Ticket, TicketViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Company, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.Company ))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TicketState, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.TicketState))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TicketPriorityName, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.TicketPriority.Name)
        );
```

Ticket data populated in query, but not projected to TicketDto:

[image]

How to correctly configure mapping for TicketViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [#5984640](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984640/automapper-class-and-nested-class-map-to-one-class), i figured it out:

```
configuration.CreateMap<Ticket, TicketDto>();
configuration.CreateMap<TicketState, TicketStateDto >();
configuration.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto >();

configuration.CreateMap<Ticket, TicketViewModel>()
            // .ForMember(dest => dest.Company, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.Company ))
            // .ForMember(dest => dest.TicketState, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.TicketState))
            // .ForMember(dest => dest.TicketPriorityName, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.TicketPriority.Name)
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Ticket, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src) // <= required configuration
        );
```

The commented lines Automapper got automatically from the first mappings, so they are unnecessary.

Comment: Unless you have disabled [flattening](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) in your AutoMapper config, you shouldn't need the `.ForMember(dest => dest.TicketPriorityName, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.TicketPriority.Name)` mapping - it should work automatically.

Comment: Does the last mapping automatically map `Ticket` to `TicketDto`?

Comment: @GertArnold Actually yes, it is. But it's not quite clear why Automapper works this way. CreateMap<Ticket, TicketDto>() is not necessary for current scenario.