# automapper ProjectTo need to convert a nullable<long> into a bool

Tags: c#, automapper

I have been tasked with looking after a web app that was built using automapper to complete all data transformations. So far, I have managed to get most issues sorted out, but I have one that is turely perplexing, at the moment.

In the database, I have a field called HasDocuments which is defined as a bigInt.

[image]

This field holds hierarchy data, but for this viewModel, it is used as a flag just to show if a value is present.

So my viewModel has a proptery defined as a nullable bool.

```
public bool? HasDocuments { get; set; }
```

All good so far.

When the call to the database is made

[image]

I have checked all of the mapper cfg to check and none of them are called and come across some great articles on SO like:

[AutoMapper ProjectTo() configuration question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164963/automapper-projectto-configuration-question)

From articles I know that the ProjectTo command is different to the MapFrom command.

I am just not getting what is going on here.

Can anyone please help?

**UPDATE**

As per request the following is the mapping config.

```
  CreateMap<Parcel, BaseParcelDataContract>()
            .BeforeMap((s, d) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("");})
            .Include<Parcel, ParcelDataContract>();
```

Parcel is the base DB object and has HasDocuments property as nullable long, BaseParcelDataContract is passed back to the Controller and has the HasDocuments property as a nullable bool.

Comment: Show us your Automapper configuration please.

Comment: I will edit the post with the details.

Comment: How about using aftermap?

Comment: To be fair, the BeforeMap is duplicated as an AfterMap, the only reason why I did not show it, was because the BeforeMap is not hit on my breakpoint

Comment: See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options). You have to do that conversion yourself with MapFrom, ConvertUsing or anything else that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank Luican for his answer. In the end, I used a straight  left => right swap. But yes Luican. Automapper cannot do this. Unless anyone can show me.

Award to Luican.